# Django nested serializer giving me None for all fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I'm working with Django and djangorestframework (versions 3.2.12 and 3.12.4, respectively) and I'm running into an issue with nested serializers.

I've got FantasyLeague and FantasyLeagueSettings models. FantasyLeagueSettings has a FK to FantasyLeague

models.py

```
class FantasyLeague(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    yahoo_league_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class FantasyLeagueSettings(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(FantasyLeague, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='settings')

    max_teams = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_playoff_teams = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    playoff_start_week = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm serializing them like so:

serializers.py

```
class FantasyLeagueSettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FantasyLeagueSettings
        fields = ['max_teams', 'num_playoff_teams', 'playoff_start_week']

class FantasyLeagueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    managers = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)    
    settings = FantasyLeagueSettingsSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FantasyLeague
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'managers', 'settings', 'yahoo_league_id' ]
```

But for some reason `FantasyLeagueSerializer(league).data` gives me a value of None for all of the settings fields (even though the settings data exists)

Testing code:

```
league = FantasyLeague.objects.get(pk=1)

print('')
print(FantasyLeagueSerializer(league).data)
# FantasyLeagueSerializer(league).data: {'id': 1, 'name': 'PLAYING FOR KEEPS', 'managers': [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('username', 'Smurflo'), ('settings', OrderedDict([('selected_theme', 'kanagawa')])), ('is_staff', True)])], 'settings': OrderedDict([('max_teams', None), ('num_playoff_teams', None), ('playoff_start_week', None)]), 'yahoo_league_id': '461051' }
# Note how all of the settings fields are None

# Even though league.settings clearly has data and FantasyLeagueSettingsSerializer works
print('')
print(FantasyLeagueSettingsSerializer(league.settings.all()[0]).data)
# {'max_teams': 12, 'num_playoff_teams': 6, 'playoff_start_week': 15}
```

Anyone know what's going on here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem is due to the uncoordinated relationship between `FantasyLeague` and `FantasyLeagueSettings`.

if instances of `FantasyLeague` can have more than one settings, then you should change `many=False` to `many=True` in `settings` field of `FantasyLeagueSerializer` serializer.

```
class FantasyLeagueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    settings = FantasyLeagueSettingsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ...
```

but if `FantasyLeague`'s instances can have at most one settings, then you should change `league`'s type to `OneToOneField` in `FantasyLeagueSettings` model.

```
class FantasyLeagueSettings(models.Model):
    league = models.OneToOneField(FantasyLeague, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='settings')
    ...
```